# Mocks for AEM application

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, aem

we are trying to learn a Unit testing Framework for AEM applications.

We gone through some documentation for 
**- ResourceResolver mock
- sling mocks
- JCR mocks
- OSGI mock
- AEM mocks** 
But didn't get clear understanding of that, If anyone have expertise in it please do share some code demos for above topics

Thanks,
Gunesh Mahajan

Comment: This question is not specific enough. You could book an expert to give you an extensive session on testing. https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html pretty much sums everything up.

Answer (score 3):

In unit testing we do not have the JCR and OSGi objects.

For e.g. 
if your code contains a Search Query then you will need access to a javax.jcr.Session session. You will also need a ResourceResolver to fetch resource.

Code will be somewhat like:

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(properties);
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
```

So in unit testing you will need to send mock of such objects since you cannot get actual versions of the same. A mock is just a dummy object so that you do not get a null pointer in your test cases. Using mocking frameworks like Mockito, JUnit, PowerMock etc., you specify the output of the method calls on mocks.

e.g.

```
@Mock
ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

@Mock
Session session;

@InjectMocks
YourMainClass objectOfYourMainClass;
```

Then using whenThen statements you specify the expected behaviour in tests.

when(mock.methodCall).thenReturn(expectedReturnObject);

e.g.

```
when(resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class)).thenReturn(session);
```

PowerMock is a framework used to mock classes which are not possible using basic Mocking frameworks. e.g. Static classes can be mocked using PowerMock.

You can visit the Powermock github link for info about PowerMock.

Please refer the following links for more information about Mocking:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-mocking-java

Comment: Haven't really used Sling Mocks till now. Will check it out.